# What is "what is"?

Tags: metaphilosophy

A lot of questions we ask have the form: "What is ..."
Some examples would be :

> What is love?
>        What is the square root of 34?
>        What is this object?

But what is the answer to the question "What is "what is"?" ? in other words, when we ask a "what is question" what are we expecting?

Comment: We are expecting a definition that capture teh "essence" of the concept.

Comment: See [Aristotle and essence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essence): "The concept originates with Aristotle, who used the Greek expression *to ti ên einai* (τὸ τί ἦν εἶναι, literally meaning "the what it was to be" ) or sometimes the shorter phrase *to ti esti* (τὸ τί ἐστι, literally meaning "the what it is") for the same idea. "

Comment: I am also partial to "essence", but you may find this book interesting too:  Title: The alienation of reason; a history of positivist thought,  Author: Kołakowski, Leszek.   Publisher:Doubleday,Pub date:1968. Kolakowski is well known so you find this book translated into many languages, it may have been originally in Polish.

Comment: You are asking about Ontology, the central question for which is 'What is?'.

Comment: The element operator with a free variable on the right hand side?  In that case we are expecting an inventory of classes which contain the object, or a good guess as to which of those classes is most relevant to our context.  One does not have to assume essences exist in order to believe language works.

Comment: It is what it is.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAxzr9BdnkA

Comment: Love is love. The square root of 34 is the square root of 34. And this object is this object. When the tautology group has a million members, the tautology group will have a million members.

Comment: Might be useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_analysis

Comment: @barrycarter: can a question be a tautology at all? What does philosophy have to say on this?

Comment: An incomplete sentence.

Comment: Short version "what is" is a copula. [Long version](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/63985/37256)

Comment: ‘What is’ consists pf phonemes that carry meaning themselves besides the words they form. The meaning of the words has become dominant over the meaning of the phonemes as words developed from phonemes and compounded meanings of phonemes to a meaning in a word. This is common in language but the research on it is practically zero. Alas because the phonemes in words still contain an ocean of deeper meanings than most linguists are willing to accept.

Comment: I think this discussion is related: '"Why ask why" and its scions' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/79366/why-ask-why-and-its-scions/79438#79438 You are basically turning 'what is' into a 'why' question

Comment: Related: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/106597/how-should-one-answer-the-question-what-is-x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleuze is very interesting on this point; one of the only (“continental”) thinkers I can suggest who is — at least in certain works, *Difference and Repetition* in particular — concerned explicitly with the philosophical implications of question-forms. A rough gist might be that *what*-prefixed question statements are less interesting or important for thinking (and so for philosophy) than question-forms like *where?*, *when?*, *how many?*, *which one?*

There is a specificity to these latter, non-*what?* questions; they correspond to what Deleuze calls “spatiotemporal dynamisms” which dramatize a concept — and so express ideas more effectively than *what is...?* problem-forms, which seem to call for a transcendent essence.

(This seems like a theme Derrida might have considered, perhaps at length, but I’m not sure in what works this might appear.)

As suggested above there is definitely a long history of analytic thinkers doing philosophy of language and wondering/working on the problem of question forms, but I’m not really very familiar with it; SEP as usual has [a good review](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/questions/).

Comment: The "what" as in "what happened" is really important however: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Ws#Etymology, http://www.cegepsherbrooke.qc.ca/~paradesquare/files/EFFECTIVE%20CALL%20TAKING%20v3.pdf

Answer (score 4):

''Is'' is used in place of a more specific implied meaning such as ''is the essence of'', ''is the definition of'', ''physically constitutes''.

Comment: Analytically minded-philosophers call it a copula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)

Answer (score 3):

Derrida spends some time on the general structure of a question in [Heidegger: The Question of Being and History](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/H/bo23044222.html), page 28:

> One must know what a question in general is to determine what the
> question of being must be. This structure cannot be drawn without the
> three poles of the *Gefragtes*, the *Befragtes* and the *Erfragtes*.
> What does this mean?
>
> Every question is a seeking and as such it has an object (*Gesuchten*)
> about which it is concerned. Every question has an object *asked
> about* ... *“Das Fragen hat als Fragen nach sein Gefragtes [ . . . ]”
> (Sein und Zeit, 4).* But every question also inquires of something ...
> — Heidegger does not say “address a question to” but “inquire of
> something” (*Anfragen bei*). *“Zum Fragen gehört ausser dem Gefragten
> ein Befragtes” (Sein und Zeit, 5).* “Besides what is asked about, what
> is interrogated also belongs to questioning” (here the asked about,
> *Gefragten*, is being, the interrogated (*Befragtes*) is beings) *(Being and Time, 4)*. And then the intention that guides the question, what makes one pass from the *Befragtes* to the *Gefragtes*,
> from what is interrogated to what is asked about, if you like, is the
> *Erfragtes*, translated [by Stambaugh] as “what is to be ascertained.” This fundamental and formal structure which is that of any question is
> further determined if one thinks that it can be a question posed just
> like that ...

Answer (score 1):

**This term is often used for getting the **MINIMUM** requirements for creating a mental picture of something.**

We can use "What is" for the minimum information (as a word) and also for a very extensive explanation that contains different types of information.

Let's check whether the usage 'MINIMUM' is correct or not.

A person (especially, if he doesn't know English well) often uses/can use "What?" to mean "What is?" if he can't hear or understand the question he was asked; no matter whether it is a wh-question or a yes-or-no question.  The shortest response will be "What?" to mean "What is?".  Here "What?" is used just for repeating, sometimes for an explanation.  So we can confirm that the usage 'MINIMUM' is correct.

Other wh-question words can be reworded using "what", I think.

E.g.:

**When**    ---     at what time

**Where**   ---     at what place

**Who**     ---     what person

**Which**   ---     what one or ones

**Why**     ---     for what reason

**How**     ---     in what way or manner; by what means.

(You will have to add "is" to each word given above.)

I think this is possible with other wh-question-words also.

If all these question-words (given above) can be compared to tools, "What is" acts as our hand for holding those tools. I mean, other wh-question-words would be useless without the help of "what is" (as its base).

E.g.: The question, "Who is that person?" won't be meaningful if it doesn't mean "**What is** the name of that person?", "**What is** his relationship with this area/the other person?" etc.

https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/wh-question-words.htm

To summarize:

"What is" is an alternative term that can be used to indicate any wh-question-words. So it can mean all the meanings that wh-question-words imply.

In short, ***it is a Panacea***.

Answer (score 0):

**What** is defined as **something**. So for example the question, What is love? may be rephrased as a statement: "Something is love" or "Love is something".

Therefore "what is" may be restated as, "something is".

what is = something is = is something

All three of the above statements may also be posed as questions.

Something / (some thing) is defined as, "a thing not definitely known, understood, or identified; a thing undetermined; a thing unspecified".

Therefore, "What is X?" means: "An unknown thing is X." or **X = X**

[Webster's New 20th Century Dictionary, unabridged, c1959]

Answer (score 0):

The phonemes in ‘what is’ have meaning themselves.

The word ‘what’ and Old English hwæt are cognate with Arabic هذا هو؟ (hadha hw?) meaning ‘this is?’. ’What’ has been compounded in English to mean ‘what’ from ‘this is’ and because it is compounded the verb ‘to be’ can be added to ‘what’ to equate with it.

Example: What is a man?
Phonemic: Is this, is man?

The word ‘is’ shows a relation to support (as the letter Samek is too. 
What is therefore finds its origin in the description: ‘this is’ and ‘support’. What is a man or Does this support being a man? Quod/Quoi finds a cognate  in ‘equate’. The use of support/equate is metaphoric in information context.

Question
 क्या वस्तु है यहाँ
kya vastu hai yahaan
What is the object here

As you can see, the word ‘question’ originates in a more concrete context. This is common in abstract terms.

Comment: From the opening of Beowulf, with translation: Hƿæt ƿē Gārde/na ingēar dagum þēod cyninga / þrym ge frunon...
"Listen! We of the Spear-Danes from days of yore have heard of the glory of the folk-kings..." 'Hwaet' is also sometimes translated 'behold'. Another interpretation is as declaratory 'How -' https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/books/news/listen-beowulf-opening-line-misinterpreted-for-200-years-8921027.html The Viking word 'thing' that might be used as answer, also has had interesting shifts in meaning.

Answer (score -1):

What is "X", is a convenient form/method, for the person making the inquiry, to obtain the listener's understanding/definition/knowledge of "X".