# Do nominalists predicate everything equivocally?

Tags: logic, nominalism

Do nominalists [predicate](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/37148/2014) everything [equivocally](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/equivocation-logic)?

[Equivocal](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/equivocation-logic) predication is when only the name is common between two things, for example: "bark" in tree bark and dog's bark.

Comment: It is at least [possible](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/63985/37256) that predicat(ion) is – at least at times – more linguistic than essential. [More at](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/64933/37256)

Comment: Was there a specific event or observation that brought this question to mind?

Comment: @MarkAndrews The definition of equivocal prompted my question.

Comment: It’s just that this seems like a good question, and I wanted to avoid closing the question for lack of clarity.

Comment: Recent views emphasize that nominalists are of 2 kinds: rejecting universals or rejecting abstract objects. The 2nd kind does not perhaps fit the question which seems to be historical and not just logical (as the 2nd comment above hints).

Comment: @sand1 Yes, perhaps my question does amount to asking about the problem of universals.